# What is MTK Logger?

Tags: default-applications

At the moment I am using an alcatel One Touch Pixi. I'm currently deleting apps that I don't use and found MTK Logger.

What is the MTK Logger app and what it is used for?

Comment: If it's a system app and doesn't come from Google, please don't delete it, no matter how insignificant it is, unless you've made a [tag:nandroid] backup.

Answer (score 4):

MTK Logger saves all events (from other apps or hardware like connecting to charge) to SD card files as text. It takes a lot of space.

To turn it off, find a file configuration `mtklog-config.prop` in `/etc` folder and edit the value from `true` to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

MTK Logger only records the user actions performed. For example, if you've opened the camera, a text file will be saved in MTKLogger having information about that particular action.

The MTKLogger file size in my Lenovo K8 was exactly 11.35GB. I just performed the clean operation using SHAREit's CLEANit option and it is safe to delete as this doesn't affect any of your data.

Answer (score 0):

To delete MTKLogger:

1. Run file manager app, file directory will be shown
2. Search through the tablet directory for the `mtklog` directory
3. Highlight `mtklog`
4. Delete by selecting the dustbin icon

Answer (score -2):

It steals your information. Should be removed

Comment: Could you add some sources or other justification for why people should believe your answer? We expect answers here to be backed up, not just wild accusations.

Comment: It does log a lot of information about your device, and contains security holes through which other apps may obtain this (search for "Kryptowire BLU MTKLogger", for instance), and there is no good justification for why it should remain on your phone. Remove it, or better yet: get a ROM without it.

Comment: @RolKau, you should add this as an answer instead of a comment (assuming it's true and you can provide some reliable references to the claims).

Comment: @RolKau I've unprotected the question in case you want to post an answer.