# Purpose of MTK Logger

Tags: privacy, logging, mediatek

All phones with Mediatek processors have this pre-installed logging application and the data it collects is massive,right up to the plugging/out of the phone from the charger.

What is this service targeted towards? One could say for troubleshooting and modding purposes but Mediatek generally targets the lower end (*limited-capabilites but affordable*) market.
Besides,I don't think I've heard of any other chip maker that ships out built-in data loggers.

EDIT:My question does not pertain to what this service does(which has been covered in other questions) but to the reason for the existence of such a program.I understand that it's difficult to answer this question so even headers would do the job.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MTK Logger Application](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/139046/mtk-logger-application)

Comment: I went through the answers there before posting, but the answers didn't cover as to WHY it is a full fledged application. They also don't explain why such detailed datapoints are covered by the logger.

Comment: You should mention in your question which questions you have already gone through and what they miss. Asking duplicate questions is discouraged.

Comment: MTK chips are usually used in mid and low-end phones, however MTP also provides high-end chips like "Dimensity 1000 5G". Regarding the "why" I can only guess. I know that MTK based devices are very popular with companies developing/selling Android based custom devices that are no general purpose Android (smartphone) systems such as devices for banking (TAM generator, document signing, ...) or medical accessories. May be MTK logger should help people developing such devices.

Comment: @Robert So does it mean that this service is present in the "software blueprint" of all MediaTek chips?

Comment: I have not developed an MTK based device but that would be from my perspective a reasonable answer.